# What does "pass existence" mean in this context?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Primitive people, like children and animals, are simply civilized people with the lid off, so to speak — the heavy elaborate lid of manners, conventions, traditions of thought and feeling beneath which each one of us **passes his or her existence**.

This is a sentence from Aldous Huxley's "Sermons in Cats". I've never seen the verb "pass" used with "existence" before. How should I interpret this?

Comment: It means "to spend (time)".   *He passes time in jail carving figurines in soap with a spoon.*   The phrase is synonymous here with "spends his or her lifetime". Another defining phrase would be "to live out": "... beneath which each one of us lives out his or her existence".  **existence** is being used as a synonym for "lifetime".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's common to say "pass time" to mean do something just to be busy or to avoid boredom. Like, "While I was waiting for my appointment, I passed time by reading a magazine."

It appears that "pass existence" her is a variation of that usage. He is talking about what people do to fill up the time during their "earthly existence".

Answer (score 0):

In your example

> passes

is synonymous with "**living**", e.g. "*passing*" through life.

A commonly used phrase when someone has *died* is

> They have **passed**.
>   They have **passed away**.

The meaning of the end of your passage is

> beneath which each one of us **passes his or her existence**
>   beneath which each one of us *lives his or her life*.